# Keycloak - resource protection in a group hierarchy

Tags: keycloak

I've been reading the documentation and am confused how this should be structured in keycloak.

## Setup

REST Application to serve data ( /users/{id} )

**Large **number of users organized in a **hierarchy **of many groups (stored in external DB, but can be imported or UserProviderSPI created).

Users in the parent hierarchy group can view all descendants data

The authenticated user, must be in a higher level group to see /users/{id}.

How should

- keycloak be organized?
- /users/{id} be protected?

Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.